# Pandas Profiling - KeyError: 'Requested level (var1) does not match index name (None)'

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, keyerror, pandas-profiling

I am receiving  `KeyError: 'Requested level (var1) does not match index name (None)'`. , on running the below code.

*pandas_profiling version = 2.8.0*

**Code:**

```
Profile = df_NYC.profile_report(title = "NYC Flight Data Profiling before Pre-processing")
```

**Error Message:**

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _validate_index_level(self, level)
   1414         elif level != self.name:
   1415             raise KeyError(
-> 1416                 f"Requested level ({level}) does not match index name ({self.name})"
   1417             )
   1418 
KeyError: 'Requested level (var1) does not match index name (None)'
```

I am not sure how to fix this? Could anyone help with the same?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this error when I was running pandas-profiling version 2.3.0, but it went away after upgrading to version 2.8.0.  I don't know if you're using pycaret, as well, but when I installed pycaret verion 1.0.0 it downgraded the version of pandas-profiling from 2.8.0 to 2.3.0.  I confirmed this with a "pip freeze/conda list" after installing pycaret.

Unfortunately, this means that I'm only able to have pandas-profiling v2.8.0 OR pycaret v1.0.0 installed, so I'm using two separate virtualenvs to separapte these two packages.  But I no longer see this error.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine after upgrading my pandas-profiling to version 2.8.0